# PrimeFaces dialog framework - closing dialog using remoteCommand, parent method not fired

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

JSF 2.2; PrimeFaces 5.3

My goal is to capture user closing dialog by clicking X button, go back to parent page so data can be refreshed and update form.

I was able to get p:remoteCommand to call my confirmAndCloseDialog() method in DialogBean, but the onDialogReturn() method in ParentBean is never called. Why is onDialogReturn not called? Any way I can get it to work?

BTW if a user would exit out dialog the normal way, i.e. close the dialog by clicking p:commandButton (CLOSE DIALOG), then everythign is fine.

Here are my codes.

Thank you!

Parent page:

```
<h:form>
...
    <p:commandButton value="Open dialog" 
                     id="openDialogButton"                                   
                     actionListener="#{parentBean.openDialog()}"
                     update="@form">
        <p:ajax event="dialogReturn"
                listener="#{parentBean.onDialogReturn}"
                update="@form"/>
    </p:commandButton>
...
</h:form>
```

Dialog page:

```
<body style="height: 80%;" onunload="userClickOnX();" >
    <h:form id="aForm">
         <p:remoteCommand id="userClickOnX" 
                          name="userClickOnX" 
                          actionListener="#{dailogBean.confirmAndCloseDialog}"/>
       ......
         <p:commandButton id="closeDialog" 
                          value="CLOSE DIALOG" 
                          actionListener="#{dialogBean.confirmAndCloseDialog}"/>
    </h:form>
</body>
```

ParentBean

```
public void openDialog() {
    Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("modal", true);
    options.put("draggable", true);
    options.put("resizable", true);
    options.put("closable", true);
    options.put("contentWidth", "100%");
    options.put("contentHeight", "100%");
    options.put("width", 1000);
    options.put("height", 800);
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("dialog", options, null);
}

public void onDialogReturn(SelectEvent event) {
   refresh data ....
}
```

DialogBean:

```
public void confirmAndCloseDialog() {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().closeDialog(objectForParent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

4 years later, Primefaces' dialog framework default closable "X" button is still just a link and uses javascript to hide the dialog, that is why the dialogReturn event isn't fired on using said button. I don't know a way to "intercept" its action. So if you don't want to have a custom button closing your dialog, you're out of luck, BUT you can always reinvent the wheel, kind of:

- Copy Primefaces's button and make it better :)

```
<h:body>
  <h:form id="formToolbar">
    <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-icon ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#" 
        role="button"
        style="float: right; position: relative; top: -10px; left: -3px; color: #757575;" 
        onclick="close()">
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
    </a>
    <p:remoteCommand id="close" name="close" action="#{dialogController.close()}"> 
    </p:remoteCommand>
  </h:form>
  ...
<h:body>
```

You can tweek the position and color to your liking

- In the dialog bean:

```
public void close() {
  PrimeFaces.current().dialog().closeDynamic(null);
}
```

- Now you can expect the returnDialog event in the parent page and respective bean.

```
<p:commandButton action="#{parentBean.openDialog(param)}">
  <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{parentBean.handleReturn()}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

- Remember to set closable to false when opening the dialog otherwise you will have two "X" buttons:

```
Map<String,Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
options.put("closable", false);
options.put("draggable", false);
PrimeFaces.current().dialog().openDynamic(
    "dialog",
    options,
    null)
```

PS: I set draggable to false as well, you can still use draggable mode, but this creates a bar on top of the dialog that's not reachable inside the dialog's page, so your "X" button would be positioned a little more towards the bottom which isn't aesthetically pleasing. Hopefully dragging isn't a must.

Comment: _"I don't know a way to "intercept" its action."_ via javascript eventhandlers with the use of jquery if you want

Answer (score -1):

Have you setup the Dialog Configurations?
As per: http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf
faces-config.xml

```
<application>
 <action-listener>
org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener
 </action-listener>
 <navigation-handler>
org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler
 </navigation-handler>
 <view-handler>
org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler
 </view-handler>
</application>
```

Also - your : 
should be inside the dialog div/contruction, not inside the button you're selecting.

Comment: I do have those primefaces settings in my faces-config.xml. If user click on a commandButton to close the dialog, it will return to parent no problem. But when confirmAndCloseDialog() is triggered by remoteCommand, it does not return to parent. What do you mean by "your : should be inside the dialog div/contruction, not inside the button you're selecting", my form?

Comment: sorry the p:ajax.. not sure why it didn't come out

Comment: I am not sure about that. In PrimeFaces' showcase, p:ajax is inside the commandButton. see http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/data.xhtml But I will give it a try!